# Баг ВКонтакте с беседами

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добавил страницу в беседу `->` написал туда парочку сообщений `->` отправил запрос на сервер, получил нормальный `json`-ответ с `id`, `chatId` и всем прочим, открываю диалоги в браузере - и вижу дикий лаг:
Здесь вместо названия беседы - `undefined`, вместо текста - `<название беседы>`+`" "`+`<текст последнего сообщения>`. Если открыть, то можно не увидеть сообщения (раз на раз не приходится), а если отправят ещё - то вместо title (темы) сообщения будет название беседы. 
Что это вообще такое?
Попытался отправить запрос, но вылезла `ошибка 7` (нет доступа), хотя получил [максимальный уровень доступа](https://vk.com/dev/permissions),
нахожусь в беседе и сам отправлял сообщения.

UPD: даже удалить историю сообщений не могу, вк зависает.

UPD: от браузера не зависит. Проблема от ВК.

UPD: проверил с основной страницы вк - всё работает.

UPD: Исключить из эту страницу тоже нельзя, `Internal server error #57253575`

UPD: создал беседу, куда добавил три бота одновременно (предыдущая существует давно), и в ней всё отлично работает. Не понимаю.

---

Не совсем понятно, с чем это связано, но со всеми последующими беседами всё работает хорошо. Также, для первой беседы присваивается `chatId`== `2000000000`, а для следующих `1`, `2`, ...

Comment: `https://pp.userapi.com/c638928/v638928565/33298/O5OmNgjUQf8.jpg (не загружается сюда` - всё прекрасно загружается, просто надо внимательно посмотреть на тулбар и найти соответствующую кнопку

Comment: По сабжу ответить можете, или только умничать? Я с пк загружал картинку, и imgur не отвечал, пришлось так.

Comment: Могу ответить, но на хамство буду только умничать, да.

Comment: Изначально хамства не было, а вы поступили крайне умно, да.

Comment: Запросы в поддержку ВК лучше отправлять непосредственно в поддержку ВК. В самом факте подобного бага я не вижу ничего эм странного.

Comment: Мне, как адекватному и не совсем опытному человеку, стоило усомниться сначала в себе, а уже потом в платформе ВК. Поэтому я решил спросить здесь, вдруг это я где-то ошибся :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Баг встречается, если у пользователя ещё нет диалогов, а его сразу пригласили в беседу. Ещё не исправлен, ВКонтакте давно были оповещены.

Решение: если ведёте разработку бота для бесед и т.д. (он будет работать на личной странице, а не в сообществе) - сначала напишите от его имени в любой диалог, и лишь после этого добавляйте его в беседы.